# How to call instance variable method with variable arguments from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to call a function with variable length arguments stored in an array. 
I noticed that you can do this with `call_user_func_array($callback, $array);`
However it doesn't seem to work on instance variable methods.

```
class foo{
  $iVar 

  function A{
      $anArray = array(...);
      call_user_func_array(iVar->methodName,$anArray);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong there. First, `iVar` is not a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), so it should begin with a `$`. And since it is a property of `foo`, it should be `$this->iVar`.

Secondly, you cannot pass a [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) like that. You have to pass it as a [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). So in total, the call should look like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->iVar, 'methodName'), $anArray);
```